# Imprimir el valor de una llave de HoH

Tags: imprimir

cree un HoH de 2 dimensiones:
1- Formada por el día
2. Formada por tiempo hora:minuto

Lo despliego correctamente:

```
for my $dia (sort keys %HoH){
     print "<br>$dia: <br>";
         for my $horarios (sort keys %{$HoH {$dia}}){
             print "$horarios=>" . $HoH{$dia}->{$horarios} . "<br>";
         }
}
```

SIN EMBARGO AL IMPRIMIR EL VALOR PARA EL SIGUIENTE ELEMENTO LO MUESTRA VACIO Y SI EXISTE UN VALOR QUE DEBERÌA SER MOSTRADO Y NO MUESTRA NADA:

print $HoH{"2023-01-01"}{"00:00"}; #NO DESPLIEGA NADA

AGRADECERÈ SU APOYO PARA PODER IMPRIMIR EL VALOR.

Respetos para Ustedes.

Comment: NO TIENES QUE GRITAR. Sin mayúscula sostenida es todo más amable en la Internec

Comment: No fue mi intención, disculpas a todos